# Aggregate query with distinct subquery kills every connection

Tags: mysql

This query ( from any client, cli, workbench, dbeaver, php library ) completely kills every single connection on the server in mysql 8.0.16, runs as expected on 8.0.15.

```sql
SELECT SUM( `x` )
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    `T`.`x`
  FROM
    JSON_TABLE(
      '[1]',
      '$[*]' COLUMNS(
        `x` INT PATH "$"
       )
     ) T
  ) y;
```

Using a temporary table instead of the subquery works as expected ( it DOES NOT crash every mysql connection )

Anybody run into this issue ?

EDIT: Sorry didn't make this clear, has nothing to do with the SUM method,  seems like any aggregate function ( GROUP_CONCAT, JSON_ARRARYAGG ... ) with a distinct subquery crashes every connection on 8.0.16

Answer (score 2):

It looks that the problem is `DISTINCT`(most likely a bug):

```
SELECT SUM( `x` )
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `T`.`x` FROM
   JSON_TABLE('[1]','$[*]' COLUMNS(`x` INT PATH "$")) T
) y;
-- error

SELECT SUM( DISTINCT `x` )
FROM (
  SELECT  `T`.`x` FROM
   JSON_TABLE('[1]','$[*]' COLUMNS(`x` INT PATH "$")) T
) y;
-- correct
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09a684778f92ff8ef76f32f5178963d7)**

EDIT:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  `T`.`x` FROM
   JSON_TABLE('[1]','$[*]' COLUMNS(`x` INT PATH "$")) T
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT  /*+ NO_MERGE(cte) */  * FROM cte
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(`x`)
FROM cte2
```

It seems the issue is with materialization even without using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg MySQL bug, the query itself is correct

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there is no JSON_ARRAYAGG ( DISTINCT ... ) syntax

Comment: It seams to be working on MySQL 8.0.12.. See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/totJDsCCfdwE3qJc3mj9yv/2)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, it is. Please compare version 8.0.12 vs 8.0.16 (regression)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, now I see that you have editted(deleted and posted new) comment :)

Comment: Indeed.. but it indeed seams to be a bug in MySQL 8.0.16...to bad bug reporting on the oracle website is so trouble some..

Comment: Thanks! Deleted my comment before I saw yours. I raised a bug in MySQL's issue tracker: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95826

Comment: @RaymondNijland, troublesome, but hopefully worth it.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg see [these](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dc9a00cf604315b4915aa33082c0a6b) cases as well not sure if you can still update the bug report.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Please also see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2188404825aa7d38d64496e2085fe7b4 There is a problem with materialization without using DISTINCT at all: `/*+ NO_MERGE(cte) */` will cause an error